# Phalcon: server not reachable through ip after installation

Tags: centos, installation, centos6, phalcon

I tried to install Phalcon on CentOS 6.5. This is what I did:

- Edit etc/yum.conf: remove the line ‘exclude=’ (temporarily)
- Terminal:

1. Sudo yum update (to update everything on the system)
2. Yum install php-devel
3. Sudo yum install git
4. git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
5. cd cphalcon/build
6. sudo ./install

- Add a file called phalcon.ini in /etc/php.d/ with this content:
  extension=phalcon.so
- Put back the original etc/yum.conf file
- Reboot server.

Before I rebooted the server, "Apache is functioning normally" was displayed when I typed the IP address in my browser. Now when I got there, I get a browser message about being unable to establish a connection. When I type :2222 after the ip address, I can get access to directadmin.

What did I do wrong? (this is the second time I tried to reinstall it completely...)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't properly install Phalcon when using DirectAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon should be loaded after all other PHP extensions are loaded. This has to do with the patches used by CentOS: they change the way the extensions are loaded into PHP.

I would remove `extension=phalcon.so` from php.ini and create `/etc/php.d/zz-phalcon.ini` with

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

and restart the web server.

**EDIT**: I explained this in details in the [official forum](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/664/after-upgrading-from-php5-5-to-php5-5-1-an-error-occurs).